# What to do when user deletes question before you can post answer

Tags: discussion, support

Basically I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794512/how-to-merge-identical-keys-and-add-their-values) *<sup>(deleted now)</sup>* which needed a solution to group up a json result set. I had just worked out the answer and was about to post it when i got the infamous:

```
Page Not Found
This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

We couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find this program.
```

How can I let the OP know the answer, if viable?

Or how would I go about this? Go sit in the corner and cry myself to sleep? :P

Comment: If the OP deletes the question, that's their business. They may have been downvoted, found the answer themselves, or they may even have deleted it to edit it a bit before they undelete it as a way to avoid downvotes (unlikely). There's no way to contact them unless they have explicitly provided contact information on their profile (which is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]).

Comment: @AstroCB I thought as much, only issue is that I don't know OP's profile. From the comments I saw before it was delete, it looked like OP deleted it because they suggested he didn't supply relevant code (that he attempted) to the question.

Comment: You'll have to wait for a 10k user to come along (who can see the question) and tell you who it is (I'd add that specific request to your question if you want to know that).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: deleted question's comments]

By the comments it looks like they mistook what Prix was saying to mean they should try over (try doing their question/code over maybe??) and decided to delete the question. So they might come back and post again. Though them not keeping it open while they try to some way come up with the code needed makes it so people like you can't help them.

If you believe the question is worth addressing so that others may find it and get an answer, create a question explaining the problem, in a better way so as to not get down voted, and then post a self-answer. Or wait and see if the question gets reopened, or reposted.

Otherwise nothing to do.

Comment: Do you possibly have a link to his profile so I can keep an eye out for a question he may ask?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1031822/dibesjr

Comment: If he deleted himself/herself why does it say "removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation". I have seen "voluntarily removed by user" reason before so shouldn't it be used here as well?

Comment: @Templar That's weird. When i asked this question it stated that **he** deleted it himself, now it says for reasons of moderation.

Comment: @Templar, my best guess is it has to do with the user changing their name. As you can see in the image the user was using a default user**** name, and has since changed it. I think the changing of the name did not propagate to the deletion message/system whatever. So you get the moderation message instead of the user one. Someone else that has more knowledge of the system would have to say wither my guess is right or wrong.