# What to do when the OP just won't get it

Tags: discussion

So, I've recently been trying to help someone, and I know the problem in his post, but he *just won't get it*. He's actually one of those impatient people who just want the answer no matter what. At first, he was extremely unclear and had no code whatsover, but now he has provided us with code.

---

So I solved the problem, and now I'm explaining it to him. He just won't understand, should I leave him alone? Report him (*He's becoming kind of rude*)? Here's the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159325/html-and-css-not-working-perfectly-in-different-browsers/38159907?noredirect=1#comment63754207_38159907

Comment: fwiw, I've requested clarification and/or code and/or sample data from a number of questioners. If I find the base question of value to SO then I may even write an answer and hold it in draft. On occasion I have even commented back to the OP asking if they have abandoned the question. On even fewer occasions I've waited a week and (without response) written a somewhat parallel but SO quality question and posted my original draft as a self-answer.

Comment: You have [unleashed it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327134).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Walk away. If you have done all you can do, and you can't think of any way to make it any more clear, just leave. You've done your job and there's nothing more to do.

You not engaging in the conversation any longer can have 2 positive effects (among a wide variety of possible outcomes). Either the OP gets some time to reflect on the issue and will see what you mean. Or you may at some point think of a better way to phrase your answer.

If neither of those positives happen, so be it. But from personal experience, dragging such a situation along will only get both parties frustrated.

Comment: Thought so... :P

Comment: @AbAppletic you weren't exactly defusing the situation there. I've cleared up the non-constructive comments - just walk away from this one and spend your time on someone that appreciates the time you're spending trying to help.

Comment: I completely agree with 'do not engage'. Troll or no-Troll just walk away from conflict.