# What do I do when it's clear OP cannot understand the answer?

Tags: discussion

If this is a duplicate point me in the right direction, and I'll delete it, but all I found was [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327306/what-to-do-when-the-op-just-wont-get-it), the question it's a dupe of, and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/explain-x-to-me-questions-how-to-react) one. Those seem related to the 'show me teh codez' questions. This question is about questions where the OP just doesn't have sufficient understanding to *comprehend* the answer, not just pining for a quick fix. The one about 'explain x' doesn't seem to fit either; the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851434/what-is-concurrent-option-for-async-queue-in-node-js) that sparked this one is (IMHO) specific enough.

As it stands, the answer to the question is in the API documentation of the referenced library. Having seen questions closed for that in the past, I posted the link in the comments, flagged for closure, and moved on. I thought the OP was just too lazy to search prior to posting. Now it's pretty clear that the OP just does not in fact understand what an asynchronous queue is, nor much about concurrency in general.

I see that the flag has been disputed. Perhaps I gave the wrong close reason? How am I supposed to deal with questions where the OP just doesn't get it?

Comment: _"How am I supposed to deal with questions where the OP just doesn't get it?"_ Move on. Serving PEBCAKS doesn't add any value to the site.

Comment: For context, you flagged the question as "very low quality" (not using a close flag), and that was disputed by this review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13878798 where three reviewers voted that it simply needed editing. Now, how people interpret the "requires editing" vote is a separate argument.

Comment: @BradLarson per the current on hold reason, I'm guessing I should have flagged as 'too broad'.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ PEBCAKS?

Comment: @Dbl: People creating scenarios wherein the only Problem Exists Between the Chair And the Keyboard

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thx. just found it on urbandictionary. guess there are localized descriptions for that. over here we call it a osi layer 8 problem :p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Now we have to make up the last 'S'.

Comment: @GillBates Plural.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Always have to ruin stuff

Comment: @GillBates We hate fun ya know.

Comment: @Dbl: Problems Existing Between the Chair And the Keyboard really Suck

Comment: Great use of the word "pining".

Answer (score 35):

Answer should provide answer to question *as posted*. It is up to OP to figure out what they don't understand and ask new question if needed. You can comment/chat to guide them, but are not required to.

My steps

- read question and edit to remove fluff (including "new in XXXX").
- read it again and see if it makes sense
- downvote/VTC if it still unclear/low quality, possibly comment
- answer if it is clear
- link to explanation if asked one thing/guide to ask new question(s) for any other requests.

When answering assume the reader have general understanding of language/framework concepts and need just one thing explained. You can provide additional links to detailed explanations, but are not required to do so. Don't make answer specially dumb down or unnecessarily complicated/way outside of level of the problem*.

About linked question: while it asks one very concrete and answerable thing (what is meaning of particular parameter) it essentially turned out into chameleon question - with much broader scope. Already discussed in [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) - chat/step away/guide to ask new question are common recommendation.

---

*<sub>trolling in "do my homework" is an exception where it is funny to provide overly complicated answers, but it is likely against "be nice" policy - use your judgement.</sub>

Answer (score 13):

I doubt that the dispute of the flag means that you're "wrong"; it's just that someone else believes that the question is viable and valid.

While I've often argued in defense of questions where a user doesn't understand the API, I would argue that *this* particular question isn't all that great to begin with.  What you have here is a disconnect between reading the API and relevant documentation and using Stack Overflow as a place to really break it down into bite-sized pieces for the OP.

(I would say my largest concern is that the OP claims to want to use the code, but they don't quite understand it.  That's the *really* worrying part here.)

I can't give you "generic" advice for situations like this since situations like this should be looked at case-by-case.  The heuristic I've used before (which is why I've come in defense of these questions):

- Has the asker done their due diligence in researching the question beforehand?
- Does the OP have a specific question related to the usage of the function versus a "what does this do" sort of question?

For this one, on both of these I say "no", so personally I'd be downvoting it.  Downvoting it and moving on sounds like the correct course of action here.

Duplicates aside, there's no real closure reason since:

- The question ***is*** a programming question
- It's ***clear*** what they're asking about - a specific parameter and its value in a function
- The question ***isn't*** all that broad (it's asking about this specific function)
- The question ***isn't*** about a typo as best as I can tell
- There are ***no*** opinions to be had about the value of that parameter - there are only concrete facts

...but custom closure reasons are often [ab]used to "fill" this void...

Comment: The question is functionally asking to explain what concurrency is, and how to use an asynchronous library.  It's not a specific question at all.

Comment: @Servy you are correct, although that's not what the question states in its naive formulation... does 'functionally' count is the crux of my question.

Comment: @Servy:  That's a bit of a stretch, isn't it?  The question is plainly asking about the value '2' as part of a parameter list for a function.  I won't deny that the underlying *intent* is to try to get more information about what concurrency is and how to use the library, but the question as stated doesn't ask for those things.  The best answer will point them to some form of documentation (you can hear the elation in my voice...), and the worst answer would try to explain the more broad stroke of it, which is worse.  It's a bad question, but I'm not seeing it reach that broad.

Comment: @Makoto The literal question asks to "explain it".  In order to actually explain what it means, in the context of this question, you'd need to explain what concurrency is, how it is handled by javascript, etc.  That is the *explanation* that the question is actually asking for.

Comment: @Servy:  I had to be sure I wasn't looking at the wrong question here...and no, I just don't see the "explain it" portion.  I do agree with you in that yes, the question could *expand* to ask about how concurrency works in JavaScript, but the question **as stated** doesn't.  I'm going to give the OP the benefit of the doubt in that they seem to only be asking about the value of what that parameter is in that function, which makes for a downvotable question, but not necessarily one that's closeable yet.

Comment: @Makoto Consider the code in the quote itself has a comment specifically explaining that parameter, and they've indicated in comments that they don't even know what concurrency is or comprehend the idea of parallelism, that "benefit of the doubt" is clearly false.  The question *isn't* just asking what the meaning of the second parameter of this function is.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow's model is [not a forum, but a "Question and Answer" site, where posts stay on the site to provide value to others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#255584). If a question is good enough that answers to it could help others, it has enough value to stay on the site even if the OP is not able to fully benefit from it.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801359/sql-connection-to-class) a question I encountered not too long ago where the OP appeared to not understand some of the fundamentals of C# and OOP, impairing their ability to understand what was going wrong and how to fix it. This doesn't mean, however, that it won't have value for someone else.

Answer (score -10):

> How am I supposed to deal with questions where the OP just doesn't get it?

Just move on - what prevents you from focusing on questions whose askers will understand your answer?

Comment: Perhaps a desire to uphold quality on the site and/or help steer OP towards being able to understand the answer?

Comment: hey, i agree with you!

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent AOL!

Comment: @deletevoter [This isn't a non-answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336795) If you don't think one should move on when it's clear the OP doesn't get it, then you should downvote this answer instead of voting to delete.