# Answer doesn't solve the question

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, answers

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862147/angularjs-make-use-of-object-in-top-level-controller/39862259#39862259) that solves the question I thought it solves, but only two days later the person who asked the question made himself clear. At first, he was unclear and asked for something else, but that one comment explained his question better.

After I understood his question I realized that it has many duplicates and probably an online solution. The problems I'm facing:

1. I posted an answer that not only doesn't solve the question, but also going to stay with 0 upvoting.
2. I tagged the question as duplicate, but the tag didn't take because as mentioned above, the question seems to be asking one thing, but actually is asking another thing (he literally said it in one comment and managed not to say it in the entire 1000 words question).

Should I delete my answer? Should I edit it with a reference to the duplicate question? The tag didn't take, is there anything to do about that? What would you do if you were me? Thanks!

**Edit**

This is not the 'don't answer a question that is not clear' type of problem. The person became unclear only after his comment. At first, his question was very clear and on-point. That comment he wrote made the question look absolutely unclear withe regard to what he was really asking. Example. Question:"Where can I buy some fruit?", Answer:"At the StackOverFlow supermarket on 55th street", Comment:"No, I meant only apples and only in bazaars". That's a better description.

**Edit 2**

Frustrated I went back to the question reading it very carefully, and here is what I realized.

1. In opposed to the first edit, I'm going to say this is definitely the "don't answer a question that is not clear". The lack of information given by the OP and failure to describe himself better made me think he was asking for something else.
2. It very much was a duplicate, an absolute 1-to-1 duplicate to a fairly discussed topic in AngularJS. Not only does SOF already contains many answers for this, but many articles can be found about it on the internet.
3. Self-note: Answering questions may require more attention on my side next time.

Eventually I deleted the answer as it really didn't answer what the OP was asking for, leaving aside the fact that it was a duplicate.

Comment: If a reasonable person could determine that the original question was clear and answerable, and the op changed the question after you answered it, I would move to revert back the question. Now if the original question was unclear, probably shouldn't have been answered to begin with.

Comment: @Drew The thing is, the question was very clear, it's only after that comment that you look back at the question and realize he's asking for something else. Example. Question:"Where can I buy some fruit?", Answer:"At any supermarket", Comment:"No I meant only apples and only in bazaars". That's a better description.

Comment: Basically the OP is marrying to a poor technical solution that contradicts the way angular intends you to do things, and on top of that this is not clearly explained in the question so its easy to default to explaining how to do it cleanly. Is that even salvageable? I really doubt it.

Comment: Deleting seems like a good approach.

Comment: Chameleon question? - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions. You've answered question as posted - guide OP to ask new question or give links/hints (as you've done). I've just provided answer to similar question - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335859/477420 which I think 100% applies to this situation too.

Comment: Don't be afraid to call it like it is: http://i.imgur.com/8tCdY0B.jpg . Praveen only answered that to be nice (a community wiki) assuming it would get closed and deleted fast. 30 minutes after answered the [Question Changed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39893204/revisions) . Not that the change would have mattered. Some people think a question is just a free-wheeling thing, subject to whimsical modification without showing any answer peeps any propers.

Comment: @Drew It's hard to say, the question just wasn't properly formed, I shouldn't have answered it to begin with (look at edit2). And torazaburo, I took your advice, my answer didn't serve the question well.

Comment: Alright I will take a look as I never did but was keeping things high level

Comment: yeah I don't know ng and JS so I can't comment

Answer (score 4):

> Should I delete my answer?

If it ends up having no relevance to the actual question, you may be better off deleting it. Especially if the question can be closed.

> Should I edit it with a reference to the duplicate question?

No. If it's a duplicate, close it. Don't answer it.

> The (duplicate) tag didn't take, is there anything to do about that?

Yes: Report the question to the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Keep in mind they have some [guidelines](http://socvr.org/faq) on how to report questions that really should be closed.

> What would you do if you were me? Thanks!

I would close it as duplicate (Which I've done), and deleted my answer. Luckily, I can single-handedly close JavaScript questions.