# Duplicate question by same user & same answerer... a year later

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Just stumbled upon this and found it a bit bizarre.

First someone asked this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782183/regex-which-identified-words-with-tags

Then a moment after it was closed a "different" user asked the same thing, 
somehow garnering 2 upvotes (I'm venturing a guess one of those was the account who asked the first question):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782569/regex-to-identify-words-with-tags-with-certain-conditions

Note on this one the user mentioned *"requirement is very urgent*".

Now the real head scratcher... SO sidebar pops up this one, which is the same user **a year earlier** with the same answerer and an almost identical question:
[My regex format not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940851/my-regex-format-not-working-properly)

Just curious about others' take on this.

Comment: Wild guess time: You and your buddy have the same homework problem. He teamed up with you, because you had the class before. But little did he know that you barely remember anything, and the reason you're taking it again is that you flunked the first time. But lucky you, a top user in the tag is still willing to answer your stuff. So maybe you'll all make it this time round.

Comment: @Bart for everyone's sake, I hope they fail again

Comment: @Bart that would be *so* awesome.

Comment: Well, not a student, they would never fake being a junior that works for a small company that advertises real estate in Hyderabad.  Not the kind of dream job a student ever hopes to land.  Sure it is urgent, the Prestige Song of the South project sounds way behind schedule.  Otherwise standard [regex] lossage, you post the requirement, take the regex that somebody coughs up without attempting to understand it.  And when you need it again just ask again, it is quicker than digging it back up or trying to remember what account you used a year ago.

Comment: "Awesome", "depressing", take your pick @Pekka웃 :D

Comment: We should have a "Stack Overflow Stories" section where we can collect these kinds of background stories. Really puts a human face on so many questions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have a "Hans Passant witticisms" section, @pekka?

Comment: @Cody that, too.

Comment: This thread made me sad... Till i went on the question and saw a 48K answer on there... Then i was sadder. In my morning commute and i already want a beer :(

Comment: @Patrice - And what made *me* sad was seeing someone berate the answerer for simply trying to be helpful. Those comments weren't at all constructive, and were in fact pretty insulting.

Comment: @BradLarson possible it read like that. I don't think insulting is really what I was trying to convey, sincere apologies if it looked like that. I tend to assume higher reps to be aware of these things and it may be why it looked worse than I meant it. Again, never meant to come off like that. That'll teach me to get riled up before my morning coffee. But I genuinely never intended an insult there.

Comment: ...and yeah, I was looking into this earlier and I don't see any obvious vote fraud here. At worst, I think we're seeing students or coworkers who have the same assignment.

Comment: @BradLarson - I can see that scenario - just odd that the exact moment the first question (asked by a "new" user with no rep) was closed (and then deleted), the second one appeared and instantly had two upvotes, before getting closed again.  Guess that's allowed if they are in fact two separate people, but it sure looks like the same person.

Comment: I wonder if the higher ups can see the IP address of the two users - that would probably be enough the make a call

Comment: @Pekka웃 I imagine quite a number of people would actually vote for that at area51. Damn, I actually wanna se a site like that now... filled with meta humour, bad Q&A references, and all those comments that would be "too chatty" for SO. :P

Comment: -23 on that question due to meta!!!! Is der something fishy ..... Is d OP jealous of that person .... So bizarre :P

Comment: You have [unleashed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327134/when-is-it-appropriate-to-unleash-the-meta-effect/327141) [the meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/204311#204311).

Comment: @vks - these are the breaks.  If the community liked what they saw, the question would have 27 upvotes instead.  In all fairness, it looks like the OP is in the green on rep since the question also garnered an additional 2 upvotes.  But to answer your question, yes, I am jealous of that person.

Answer (score 22):

These things do happen. This:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794761/why-did-apple-name-it-optional-binding

...is a duplicate of this:

[Optional Binding, what exactly the word "Binding" means here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821462/optional-binding-what-exactly-the-word-binding-means-here)

Well, I almost answered the later one (the first one above), but then I remembered I'd answered this sort of thing before, found my answer, and closed as a duplicate. The irony was, it was the same asker: he'd simply *forgotten* that he'd asked and been answered. But I *didn't notice* that it was the same asker, so if I had answered, we'd be in exactly the same boat: same asker, same answerer.

The moral: People are just dumb. One has to live with it. If it were a world of perfect rememberers, Stack Overflow would be out of business.

Comment: `People are just dumb.` As was to be demonstrated, yet again, by the Meta effect. -27 and counting, just because a bunch of peanut-gallery pundits here made a snap judgment that (A) the thread was a duplicate, (B) _offensively_ so, and (C) even if it had been, that gave them righteous justification to mob it and downvote it based on irrelevant non-content (Meta) reasons, rather than flagging as is the proper response.

Comment: @underscore_d When someone manages to ask the exact same question twice I think they deserve some downvotes. It's disrespectful to the people who are answering questions.

Comment: @ivarni That's funny. I think they deserve to have the thread closed or deleted as a duplicate & removed entirely from the historical record - not left up with a completely perplexing tally of votes to anyone who (lucky for them) isn't yet aware of the Meta effect. People should respond to such 'disrespect' of the rules in the appropriate way, rather than emotionally downvoting out of some weird idea that they're being personally sleighted - & _then_ paradoxically acting like they're more righteous because of it. Yet so many things on Meta seem to revolve more around the latter than the former

Comment: @underscore_d You're of course welcome to have that opinion. The OP can delete their question if they want. There's even a comment on it telling them it's an option.

Comment: @ivarni To me, it would be better to keep the more useful duplicate, delete the other, and not falsely weight the votes of the remaining one. But I think we might be past salvage here. That's what happens when people latch onto what is, really, a trivial issue that could be solved by flagging - and instead make it into a soap opera where they get to publicly shower the OP with downvotes. Just another Meta thread, IOW.

Comment: It doesn't sound like we're talking about the same thing so continuing this discussion is pointless. I see absolutely no value in having the exact same question listed twice on the site. You obviously do, in which case I'd suggest you don't delete whatever content it is you wish to keep.

Comment: We're clearly not talking about the same thing, seeing as nowhere did I say that both posts should be kept. I said one should be kept and the other flagged so that it can be deleted or closed properly, not pilloried with downvotes so that voters from Meta can feel morally superior. But yes, clearly continuing such discussions is pointless, since the mods never seem to want to do anything to pre-empt/counter the Meta effect.

Comment: @underscore_d u r one of the few talking sense here..... :)

Comment: It's unfortunate that the meta-effect greatly amplifies and exaggerates this, but I must say, I find downvoting entirely appropriate. "Lack of research effort" is one of the suggested downvote reasons in the tooltip of the downvote button, and, c'mon, how much research do you need to do to find the answer to this question when you yourself have been already given the answer?

Answer (score 14):

I answered both the questions and am not sure why they seem duplicate to people. The first one was a simple one where OP had made a small mistake. The new one is a complex one many more scenarios; in fact entirely different. The second question has a work flow, the attempt, the problem. I am not very sure why it's even being discussed. If you read the comments on the older question, the Asker gave the link to the new question today and accepted the old upon my insistence.

Comment: Yeah saw those @vks - not questioning your answer or participation here.  Just that there were the two dupes - then the question from almost exactly one year ago which was so similar.  Perhaps just a coincidence that you answered both.  The reason it's being discussed is simply because there were an inordinate number of surprising things happening all revolving around each other.  It's definitely not an attack on you.

Comment: and as I pointed out in my comment above, I do realize I came super strong in my comments on your answer. Sincere apologies for that. This was really uncalled for and was just me being too quick to rile up in the morning.

Comment: @Patrice its ok.....someday we will meet for Google Cloud Platform :)

Comment: @vks thanks for the understanding man :). I'll be happy to see you on there ;)

Answer (score 12):

There isn't much of a head-scratcher here. The [question from a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940851/my-regex-format-not-working-properly) is in the same problem domain as the recent pair of questions, but the task is sufficiently different that it just looks like someone bad at regexes trying to get more regex help. It's certainly not a suspicious degree of similarity, and the fact that the same guy answered both isn't particularly suspicious either. Someone with 2636 regex answers is going to end up answering people he's answered before.

The two recent questions *are* identical to each other, so the accounts that asked those questions are probably coworkers or sockpuppets or something.

Comment: Thanks - I was just surprised by the extreme similarity between the two questions, coinciding with the fact that they both involved the same two users almost precisely 365 days apart.  I don't find that part of it particularly suspicious - just unlikely and surprising

Comment: // , Seems surprising that you'd characterize it as a "duplicate", then.