# Why did I receive +1 rep for a non-edited and non-deleted answer?

Tags: support, downvotes

3 hours ago I got a little **+1** in my rep inbox. It says it was for an "*undownvoted*" answer.

I was under the impression that if I downvoted an answer and waited a certain amount of time that the downvote was "locked" until the answer was edited or deleted.

Well, the answer that I voted on (I don't want to post it here due to [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327134/when-is-it-appropriate-to-unleash-the-meta-effect)) was posted at 4:05AM (UTC), and I was the last one to edit it at 5:16AM (UTC). It is currently not deleted, and hasn't been edited since my last edit.

For some reason though I received the +1 for an "*undownvoted*" answer, 3 hours ago (at time of writing), or 3:29PM (UTC) .

Why is this? I did not want to undownvote the answer.

**Edit:**

[This Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) does not answer my question. It states:

> You remove a downvote from an answer or an answer you downvoted is deleted: **+1**

I know the reasons for receiving reputation back, although that question states that you receive +1 for when an answer is *edited or deleted*. In my case, the answer has **NOT** been edited **NOR** deleted and I haven't removed my downvote, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Re: 'it just says "yesterday"'. On some platforms you can hover the mouse over "yesterday" (or whatever it happens to display for the time), and it will display the exact time (to the second). It is also in the HTML source.

Comment: @PeterMortensen your right, ill edit my question. Although I don't believe this is a duplicate, as after reading the supposedly same question I still have no answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening when the following things are happening.

1. When you downvote an answer

   > it will reduce your reputation by one
2. If that question or answer removed by its owner

   > you will get your reputation back
3. If the user again added a question or answer that was deleted before

   > it will show your vote(down), but no reputation changes happen

Comment: Strange, kindof a flaw in the system - essentially someone who got downvoted on their answer could just remove it then unremove it and the downvotes will go away...

Comment: @lukakerr might still be corrected by automated correction scripts which run infrequently and generally during the night.

Comment: You said that you lose one reputation for down-voting an answer **or a question**, but it says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) that the -1 reputation is only for down-voting an answer, not a question.

Comment: @DonaldDuck sorry I'm editted