# The process of closing and re-opening questions should be more robust

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Yesterday, I [asked a valid technical question regarding WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556171).

Well, I'm an experienced software architect. I know what I'm doing and how to ask a question in a correct manner. In my question I provided a use-case, incl. sample code and I concluded my question text with two concise and clear questions, which I've been looking to be answered.

Tonight, a member closed my question as being unfocussed. Now it's not open for any answers ... and all I can do is wait for some lost souls to wander around a plethora of closed questions, randomly finding my unique question, and lower their hands on my head to give my question their absolution?

This is a professionals' forum, not some private users' home-brew fun forum. I tend to consider closing my professional question an act of sabotage. An attack by someone arbitrarily not comprehending to my valid and precise question.

This should not be allowed to happen.

So, I propose the following:

1. It should not be possible to have questions arbitrarily closed without giving a detailed reason in a comment (min. 200 characters).
2. A checkbox (labelled `needs info`) should be added to the Comments input field, requesting the original poster to provide missing information to his/her question or to update his/her question.
3. When the checkbox is checked while the comment is sent, the topic is getting flagged `stale` and the original poster is sent an e-mail with the comment requesting the update.
4. The question may then be edited by the user or a comment may be added requesting further details on the improvement request.
5. If the question has been edited, the `stale` (`needs info`) flag is getting cleared.
   (I'm not sure if this should happen automatically or if the commenter requesting the improvement should be required to approve the change.)
6. If the question has not been edited within 7 days, the question is automatically getting closed.

[BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/), for example, comes with such `needs info` Boolean flag for each comment on a bug report. That flag is associated with a recipient. When it's set, the bug gets blocked and the recipient receives an e-mail asking him to provide the missing info. Only when that info is provided (and the needs info flag gets cleared), the bug is then further processed. Stack Overflow could use a similar process.

Comment: What you describe does not seem like a “more robust” system than what we presently have.

Comment: Visiting a site for professionals and then calling fellow professionals "nitwits" when you don't agree with their actions is probably not going to go over well

Comment: You define "professional" as having 1000+ reputation, but voting to close requires 3000 reputation, so how can those people not be professional by your own standard?

Comment: It would improve the system in a way that questions could not be arbitrarily sabotaged. I apprehend there may be questions asked by beginners which tend to be rather unfocussed and need improvement. However, the opportunity to close any question without further discussion doesn't seem robust to me.

Comment: @blastfurnace: Yes, I did, an hour ago. Because the closure is based on no reason and I cannot wait for someone to take the time and re-open my original question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: This topic is not about names, it's about actions taken.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Sure, that's fine with me. I can delete the original question. I only left it open as an evidence to this case.

Comment: `I concluded my question text with two concise and clear questions` .... you must ask one and only one question per question.

Comment: For this question in particular, I know nothing about WPF, but the original question looks pretty reasonable to me. Only real issue might be the 3 questions at the bottom - *related*, sure, but maybe not related enough for all of them to be in a single question? (I don't know)

Comment: @JK: These two questions are basically *one* question: It's a pair of questions like: "(1) Does it have any color? (2) If so, what color does it have in particular?"

Comment: So, I deleted the duplicate now. May anyone please re-open my original question? (This would be nice, yet it wouldn't be the correct "answer" to this proposal, though.)

Comment: Reputation is bupkis. I have more reputation here than [Herb Sutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter) and anyone who thinks I know more about C++ than Herb Sutter needs their head examined.

Comment: @user4581301: Absolutely. I, for instance, am not a StackOverflow regular, so my reputation here is rather low. In regard to my proposal any algorithm may serve appropriate that's quite reliably telling verdant from advanced posters. (Which I tend to consider myself.)

Comment: “This is a professionals' forum” - **Except Stack Overflow isn’t any kind of forum** Why can’t you just improve your question?  Furthermore, not every SO user is a professional

Comment: “I cannot wait for someone to take the time and re-open my original question.” - Your timeline to get an answer isn’t a really a consideration in the determination if your question should be closed or remain open nor should it.

Comment: @SecurityHound: How should I improve a questions that's perfectly valid? What in particular is my original question missing? Just name it and I'll edit it.

Comment: @SecurityHound: It's not about timeline. Shall I open new copies of issues twice a week just to finally get a valuable answer to my question?

Comment: @AxD - "that's perfectly valid?" - If it was perfectly valid then it would have received upvotes and an answer.  Additionally, if you were to ask the same question as a routine more than once, you will either be suspended for doing that or question banned due to those questions not being well received.

Comment: @SecurityHound: I see your point. Yet, that's my exact improvement request here: If it's not valid, then be **clear** about the deficiencies. Explain exactly, *what parts* you feel inappropriate. Be explicit in the comments section. .. In fact, no-one, neither in the comments section of my original question nor here, is able to provide this exact information. ... Just closing a question because "My gut tells me I don't like it" ... this should not be a reason for closing a technical question.

Comment: Such explaining comment may then already be a valid and valuable answer by its own.

Comment: @AxD - In my experience when explicit specific detailed feedback is provided most users who ask a question that needs a lot of help are not typically willing to improve the quality of their question they just want an answer.

Comment: You are asking two questions there, and the second one is really broad. I don't see any reason to keep it closed otherwise

Comment: @SecurityHound: Yes, I apprehend. These cases exist. Here's my proposal to this situation: Only *after* a refining request comment would be added to a question, such question would be valid to be closed. Perhaps there could be a timeout implemented, automatically closing questions not being refined within 7 days after a comment requesting for details has been added to the question.

Comment: @oguzismail: I don't see that. Have you seen the update to my question? I added a comment to refine the second question. Someone acquainted with the intrinsic details of Visual Studio and its WPF implementation could easily and concisely answer this question.

Comment: [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/), for example, comes with a `needs info` Boolean flag for each comment on a bug report. That flag is associated with a recipient. When it's set, the bug gets blocked and the recipient receives an e-mail asking him to provide the missing info. Only when that info is provided (and the `needs info` flag gets cleared), the bug is then further processed. StackOverflow could utilize a similar process.

Comment: If you want to expand on your FR idea, I advise you you do it by editing the post, not by adding comments. In any case, the votes hint that the idea was not particularly well received by the community.

Comment: @yivi: I'd rather guess the downvotes are just cheap emotional statements, given without intellectual reason. Similar to the most upvoted comments. So, updating my suggestion with a technical detail wouldn't change the ranking, I suppose. Nonetheless, I will gladly update my suggestion now, like you suggested. Let's see if it will affect the ranking value.

Comment: I left the original reasoning in the proposal text, so everyone may comprehend the reason for my proposal. If you feel that's unnecessary, please feel free to edit my question.

Comment: I downvoted this because I *profoundly* disagree that your suggestions for changing the process surrounding closing/reopening questions would be in any way beneficial. Furthermore, I strongly disagree with the accusations you've made and the way you've painted other users with a broad brush of ignorance and unprofessionalism, simply because you disagree with their actions. This is wildly inappropriate and, as others have mentioned, quite ironically unprofessional. So, yes, I suppose in one sense, I did downvote as an  emotional statement. However, there was definitely an intellectual reason.

Comment: @CodyGray: That I can accept. To me, closing a question without providing a profound reason *is* in fact ignorant and unprofessional. The StackOverflow site is here to help, not to close.

Comment: A reason *was* given. You just disagreed with it. I also disagreed with it. That happens.

Comment: Once you have enough reputation, try posting profound comments alongside your close votes every time. The resulting experience might change your mind.

Comment: [You unleashed it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327134).

Comment: Re *"some private users' home-brew fun forum"*: That is what the majority of users and the company want (and already got?). Or is it just a vocal minority?

Comment: @SecurityHound it has actually been argued that Stack Overflow is some kind of forum. What is for certain is that it's not a discussion forum.

Comment: @AxD - "Only when that info is provided (and the needs info flag gets cleared), the bug is then further processed. StackOverflow could utilize a similar process." - This process already exists.  This is the closure of a question.  However, instead of a single user that decides if the bug report should be reopened, several users are given the opportunity to decide.

Comment: @Gimby - Who argued this exactly?  I thought Stack Overflow was a Q&A website (Quality version of Quora and Yahoo Answers) not a discussion forum (any number old programming forums that don't exist anymore).

Answer (score 21):

- It should not be possible to have questions arbitrarily closed without giving a detailed reason (min. 200 chars).

It already does have a detailed reason of min. 200 chars. As a matter of fact the [paragraph you're interested in](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) has 407 characters.

- Professional users, having a rank of 1,000+, should have the opportunity to re-open their own questions, unedited.

Unfortunately we don't have a distinction between professional and non-professional users. So that checkbox would have to be implemented first and then all users have to check that new box faithfully. Then you assume that at 1,000 reputation users somehow become super enlightened. I beg to differ.

The system currently requires that questions can be closed by 3 users that have 3,000+ reputation. That looks like a high enough bar to prevent accidental closing.  In your case the total rep involved in closing was over 100K with one professional WPF gold badge holder and two C# gold badge holders where one has an unrevealed occupation.

The re-open queue is manned with the same class of users which I think guarantees that overall quality for future visitors is maintained at a reasonable level. That might now and then conflict with personal interests but that by itself is not a good enough argument to overhaul the system and make changes that seem to match your profile perfectly.

Comment: `As a matter of fact the paragraph you're interested in has 407 characters.` - I beg your pardon: None of the content therein applies to my question.

Comment: That simply means you *disagree* with the action taken, @AxD, not that all of the accusations levied in the question are appropriate. Aside from that, mistakes do happen sometimes, but they can be easily corrected, as they were in this case. There is no need for hyperbole, overreaction, or creating a draconian process.